# Chef-Client Test one recipe in local mode

Tags: chef-infra

I want to test a new recipe as part of my cookbook, it is the first recipe I've created that is not the default recipe. Using chef-client I can do

```
chef-client -z -o my_cookbook
```

This will run the default recipe in the cookbook, but how can I run a recipe that is not the default? I've tried

```
chef-client -z -o recipe['my_recipe']
chef-client -z -j '{ "run_list": ["recipe[my_recipe]"]}'
chef-client -z -o my_cookbook_my_recipe
chef-client -z -o my_cookbook:my_recipe
```

but nothing I've tried has worked yet. How can I test just one recipe in chef local mode without making that recipe the default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-o` takes a run list so `-o 'recipe[my_cookbook::my_recipe]'`, just like you would put in any other run list. The single quotes are because some shells use `[]` as metachars.